# How to correct the [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] error for composer

Tags: php, composer-php

Good day people, I have been having this problem for days now, when I try to download dependencies for my php project using composer I get this error

```
c:\wamp64\www\Test>composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.3.1"
Changed current directory to C:/Users/Nwachukwu Favour/AppData/Roaming/Composer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "http://packagist.org/p/provider-2014%241cf88bd0ed4076dc091407477ba2a76483e8598ee5365673381262e6c1d40fcf.jso
  n" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!


require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-plugins] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--] [<packages>]...
```

I am running a windows 10 OS and am suspecting that my system cannot download from the command line. I would be very glad if someone can help me solve this problem because it is hindering my project. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could also run this command on the CLI before installing any dependencies. It forces composer to use https to download all resources:

```
composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org
```

Comment: This was suggested by a contributor to the composer project on github here https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5656. Plus, it worked flawlessly for me when i had same issue.

Comment: This also worked for me. I was getting the following error on executing composer update `[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                     
  The "https://packagist.in/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP  
  /2 502 ) `

Comment: Thanks. This solution works!!

Comment: it's not working for me.  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                      
  The "https://www.drupal.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)

Answer (score 16):

The issue could be caused by the redirect from http to https. (or your firewall blocking the call)

According to this article the problem could be solved by adding the following to your **composer.json**:

```
"repositories": [
    {
         "type": "composer", 
         "url": "https://packagist.org"
    },
    { "packagist": false }
]
```

[Forcing composer to use https connections to Packagist](http://codinginharmony.blogspot.nl/2012/10/forcing-composer-to-use-https.html#comment-form)

Answer (score 11):

I just updated my composer to the latest version and this problem is solved.

Try

`composer self-update`

To know the current version and update details:

`composer diagnose`

Answer (score 5):

I tried the command below and it worked.

```
composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org
```

This is just one of the options given above.

Comment: Thanks. It worked like charm!!

Answer (score 3):

I found enabling OpenSSL extension in the php.ini-development/production file fixed the problem.
Its located within your PHP install

Answer (score 2):

just stop your antivirus software :)

for some reason antivirus software kaspersky doesn't like composer :(

I had the same error tried everything... nothing worked.

I remembered I had issues with composer in the past while my AV was on... turned it off and composer worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 2):

just put this in command

```
composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org
```

Comment: well done!!! worked

Answer (score 1):

1. Update or Delete your 'http_proxy' variable.
2. Delete composer
3. Install Composer again
4. Restart your machine.

Your are good to go.

Comment: Can you explain that further? What kind of proxy variable are you talking about?

Comment: @NicoHaase (If you have set a variable named "http_proxy" in Environment Variables of your machine).....

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the answer by editing it

Answer (score 1):

try with `composer diagnose` and after that `composer update -vvv`

Comment: Suggestions to use commands without information about how to interpret the results of those commands, or instructions about how to roll back their effects aren't an answer. Answers added to older questions with existing answers should explain how they work, why they work, and what new aspect of the question they address.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but it was resolved in a different way for me. I used to give sudo to composer commands because folder `/home/aspire/.composer` is in sudo permission. I changed it to `sudo chown $USER /home/aspire/.composer`.

I changed the permissions as I mentioned and I ran the code

```
sudo composer require symfony/orm-pack
```

Throws error

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                      
  The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded:
```

Then I tried

```
composer require symfony/orm-pack
```

It works

If anyone know the exact reason, please comment[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are in china like me,try this:https://developer.aliyun.com/composer
github connection not stable recently.I tryed https://pkg.phpcomposer.com/ first but don't work. I tryed   composer diag  and composer -vvv and wait.out put show cache file is :Writing C:/Users/Administrator.000/AppData/Local/Composer/repo.so i copy cache file from my colleague,and it works first,laravel run,but composer require show 404.then i found the solution above.try composer update -lock and change the  repositories url to ali's.And solved.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened to me, and I solved it by turning off the firewall.
This is one of the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `http_proxy` environment variable, just delete it from either User variables or System variable and save yourself from all this trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Windows OP users: Clear "http_proxy" variable in the "Edit the system environment variables" and check it again! Then use composer "selfupdate" or "diagnose" command to check it.