# composer laravel install: “http://packagist.org” file could not be downloaded

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I want to install laravel  through composer with :

```
$ composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel DemoTest
```

but every time i do that composer shows a message:

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]   The
>   "http://packagist.org/p/provider-2013%244440cd3f9b7aec0de3e4f3486e61b7e348d74d03a0bd6a61b5b8a514e105
>   2c4d.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: HTTP
>   request failed!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correct the \[Composer\Downloader\TransportException\] error for composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996782/how-to-correct-the-composer-downloader-transportexception-error-for-composer)

Comment: What version of Composer you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

composer clear-cache

then

composer -vvv

after that try running the install command for laravel, it worked for me though