# Composer crashes when it tries to Resolve dependencies

Tags: php, laravel, docker, composer-php

I am trying to use Composer to install dependancies inside a Docker container running PHP 5.6.40.

It runs, but quits and the vendor directory is always empty.

```
MacBook:my-app dev$ docker exec my-app_php56_1 php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar update -vvv --no-cache --no-plugins
Disabling cache usage
Running 1.9.0 (2019-08-02 20:55:32) with PHP 5.6.40 on Linux / 4.9.184-linuxkit
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Checked CA file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt: valid
Executing command (/var/www/html): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Reading /root/.composer/composer.json
Loading config file /root/.composer/composer.json
Loading composer repositories with package information
Downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2013%24b962a943715f142bd3c36c0e87b67b28b16c014a98898622ec735220b7e1ee4f.json
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2014%24ecc1513d9762efcfd48fdbaf4a08f829a59093064f40b7c351f93f3fbdd07973.json
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2015%24258303eff7165b17439353fe44e501a3a6d600bd5b5482c5261a2ffa2234a947.json
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2016%2496e2313b5ba90c2b798b03f9e306a27c15f11f763cd6478b834943fc128fc111.json
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2017%24d2ad294ebaf381b7bf68cacbe514cf2bb33c3a919b97319bfa2e2ffaa66bc511.json
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2018%2466893d07acdb18bb12d5e92e062b6e3058f5d284292b09cf585bf0ceb1b26aca.json
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2018-10%24ff53e18093ae3e52a84c5567489c78bf1d82d0af80f413c3d6ad35d541a28434.json
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2019-01%2431194ef7551ee4bffd7cc09dd6d01dc60848afc129544438ac7931e9d42dd54e.json
...
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/phpspec/phpspec%248dc959bd0ae544f84e5bceee933d9a61d0a2074b208c3b7e7807cdc320e83eee.json
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/phpspec/php-diff%249b8687b7c99f069823a9ac8d17900f9c8243368ceea9a5ac4e71ab424bb6f2d5.json
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/squizlabs/php_codesniffer%24386b3726c6c3ce5edde180a7881f924be5dfd720c951dc93db8455ae871e9d61.json
MacBook:my-app dev$
```

It then just returns nothing and the vendor directory remains empty.

I am running composer without any plugins or cache.

Finally, the exact same composer.json file works fine in my other PHP 7.1.x container.

I also wondered if the final dependancies was causing an issue so tried removing it. Still no luck.

EDIT:

I've now gone back to my PHP 7.1 container and run the exact same scripts and it works fine. Composer's output is (so the 5.6 version just dies at the point that it does the "Resolving dependencies through SAT":

```
...
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/webmozart/assert%24f23cf2d90bee4a1a09dc1d005896d60e715bdb9ecd4531874bfc3dd3ea5908c1.json
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/phpspec/phpspec%248dc959bd0ae544f84e5bceee933d9a61d0a2074b208c3b7e7807cdc320e83eee.json
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/phpspec/php-diff%249b8687b7c99f069823a9ac8d17900f9c8243368ceea9a5ac4e71ab424bb6f2d5.json
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/squizlabs/php_codesniffer%24386b3726c6c3ce5edde180a7881f924be5dfd720c951dc93db8455ae871e9d61.json
Resolving dependencies through SAT
Looking at all rules.
Something\'s changed, looking at all rules again (pass #16)
Dependency resolution completed in 28.879 seconds
Analyzed 21713 packages to resolve dependencies
Analyzed 1376894 rules to resolve dependencies
Resolving dependencies through SAT
Looking at all rules.

Dependency resolution completed in 0.003 seconds
Package operations: 116 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
Installs: kylekatarnls/update-helper:1.2.0, stripe/stripe-php:v2.3.0, abraham/twitteroauth:0.6.6, ralouphie/getallheaders:3.0.3, psr/http-message:1.0.1, guzzlehttp/psr7:1.6.1, guzzlehttp/promises:v1.3.1, guzzlehttp/guzzle:6.0.2, maknz/slack:1.7.0, maknz/slack-laravel:1.0.0, sabberworm/php-css-parser:8.1.0, phenx/php-svg-lib:v0.3.2, phenx/php-font-lib:0.5.1, dompdf/dompdf:v0.8.3, vlucas/phpdotenv:v1.1.1
...
etc for everything else
```

Comment: Have you tried `composer install` instead of update?

Comment: Also, when you do the install, add the `-vvv` flag to the end for verbosity. You may see your issue that way.

Comment: 'Install' brings in the specific packages from the lock file. However my lock file does contain the correct packages for this version of PHP

Comment: Thanks, yes, -vvv is on my command along with --no-cache --no-plugins :-( As you can see, I've tried everything

Comment: Delete the lock file before you run install/update

Comment: Thanks. Yes, unfortunately I've tried deleting the lock file and the laravel cache too

Comment: The abrupt stop could be an indicator of a segfault. Have you tried running the script with xdebug enabled? This will slow things down considerably, but it might show the cause for the abrupt stop

Comment: I'm running composer inside a docker container, would that make a segfault more likely?

Answer (score 2):

From the output of your run, it seems your composer setup is using `http` rather than `https`. Run this command before installing composer:

```
composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org
```

Comment: @rob006 the command was given by a contributor to the composer project on GitHub (https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5656). I still have download issues when updating composer for my site and have used it less than a week ago. It still works as it is. Thanks anyways. I'll try your suggestion next time I update composer.

Comment: This is an old comment - meanwhile URL of repository was changed to `https://repo.packagist.org`

Comment: @rob006, have you used this command before? Pls, I'm asking this question objectively. Look at the command carefully, it contains `repo.packagist` referring to a **subdomain**. It also contains `packagist.org` which is the **main domain**. Again, `repo.packagist.org` is a subdomain under `packagist.org`. I stand by word I've used this command less than one week ago and it solved my composer issue. I am not repeating any comments. I update my Laravel site frequently.

Comment: It does not matter that it is subdomain - `repo.packagist.org` points to different server than `packagist.org`. `packagist.org` may still work due BC, but it may change in the future - `repo.packagist.org` is now correct domain for `repo.packagist` setting. See https://blog.packagist.com/an-update-on-packagist-org-hosting/

Comment: Also, I would have gladly directed the asker to the post where I suggested this in the question's comment section but his issue didn't flag a TransportException error nor was my answer there the accepted one. See the post here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996782/how-to-correct-the-composer-downloader-transportexception-error-for-composer/56696736#56696736)

Comment: @rob006, while I'm going through the hosting update link you put here, if you have used the modified version of this command before and it worked, please you can kindly edit the answer. Notwithstanding, when I get the chance to use this command again and the new version you are suggesting works, I'll change all my answer post. It skipped my mind in my last composer update.

Answer (score 0):

This question is getting a little old now so I assume you already resolved it. I had the same problem recently.

The problem appears to stem from the change of PHP version. In my case I was going from 7.1 to 7.2, which you would imagine shouldn't cause too much of an issue.

My `composer update -vvv --no-cache --no-plugins` output would show

```
Resolving dependencies through SAT
Looking at all rules.
Something's changed, looking at all rules again (pass #[forever increasing])
```

After attempting to install `symfony/thanks`

In the end I had to remove `symfony/thanks` from my `composer.json` and run again. It then gave me some problems with a few other packages that I also removed. Once I had a successful run I was then able to start adding the offending packages back to my `composer.json` and eventually the issue was resolved.

I assume the underlying issue was a number of conflicts in the various levels of dependencies of my packages.

I guess if anyone finds they end up removing more and more packages, the solution would be to start from the minimum possible packages (the default Laravel composer.json in my case) and start adding new packages one-by-one.