# A non well formed numeric value encountered in var/www/html/admin/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Traits/Units.php

Tags: php, server, composer-php, laravel-5.8, php-carbon

I am using laravel 5.8.

I am getting an exception in file `/var/www/html/admin/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Traits/Units.php` at line

```
       // @call addRealUnit
            case 'minute':
            $value *= static::SECONDS_PER_MINUTE;
            break;
```

I am using AWS server.

I am trying to run `composer update` but I am getting this error :

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>     The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to op
>     en stream: Connection timed out

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like the new warning in PHP 7.1

Probably you have an empty `SESSION_LIFETIME` in the `.env` which cause this warning by calling the `addRealUnit($unit, $value = 1)` with the `$value = ""`

**Solution:** Update the `.env` and set a value to `SESSION_LIFETIME` or remove the `SESSION_LIFETIME` and the problem should be solved.

Comment: in my opinion, the composer error has nothing to do with the exception, maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996782/how-to-correct-the-composer-downloader-transportexception-error-for-composer

Comment: Thanks, Benjamin it's working when I remove the SESSION_LIFETIME from .ENV but when I am using SESSION_LIFETIME = 525600 then it throws the same error

Comment: try to remove all spaces, probably the number gets converted in a string