# How to fix "[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]" error while installing Laravel using Composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have been trying to install Laravel using Laravel installer on Composer by entering the code `composer global require laravel/installer` on Command Line in windows.

However, after entering my code, I get the following error;

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  Your configuration does not allow connections to http://10.150.35.17:80/repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2013%249c712a50698dfae42f23e39488f51409306436007ecccf83e6f4a3
  d790b05192.json. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.
```

Anyone who knows how I can go about solving the problem?

Comment: Have you read the information on https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http?

Comment: It may cause your composer version or if you are using any antivirus, disable it and try again.

Comment: I checked the infomation on getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http but I don't know how to go about enabling or disabling the secure-http

Comment: I tried to disable the antivirus but it didn't work. What version of Composer would you recommend?

Comment: That url looks suspicious. Do you have something that is redirecting packagist calls to `http://10.150.35.17:80/<real url>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correct the \[Composer\Downloader\TransportException\] error for composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996782/how-to-correct-the-composer-downloader-transportexception-error-for-composer)

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out. I just disabled SSL/TLS protection by running the following code in command line;

```
composer config --global disable-tls true
composer config --global secure-http false
```