# Unable to use a proxy: malformed http_proxy URL

Tags: php, xampp, composer-php, localhost

I am trying to run a composer command, but I'm getting the error:

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
> Unable to use a proxy: malformed http_proxy url

What can I do to fix this error?

Here is an image showing the error message:

> [image]

Comment: Please share more details, like the current settings for the proxy

Answer (score 1):

To solve that, set the proxy to zero using the cmd

```
    set http_proxy=0
```

Answer (score 1):

I must say, I encountered this issue yesterday and have gone through all kinds of hoops to get it resolved, including watching videos and reading posts (here and elsewhere), none of which worked and potentially could have lead my naïve ass to mess up my Win10 Laptop!

- Delete *http_proxy* in Environment Variables (NO, failed to resolve)
- Uninstall/Reinstall Composer (I am on dev desktop and most steps were
  for XAMPP)
- Remove Proxy URL virus (Various methods N/A)
- uncheck Use aProxy server option (N/A)
- Run *multiple other* terminal commands for SSL etc. (NO)
- Plus multiple (outdated) YouTubes *LOL*
- run: `composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org`
- Everything is N/A from: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996782/how-to-correct-the-composer-downloader-transportexception-error-for-composer)

**This method `set http_proxy=0` worked like a charm and should be made more readily available!**

So thanks!

Answer (score 0):

uninstall composer
after install composer
in that time http proxy field is coming
u can put that one is empty only
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBm37.png
this problem is resolve

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem installing laravel. Using     set http_proxy=0 still gave me this error Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.The project folder was installed, but complained about extensions and also gave the following suggestions

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- C:\MAMP\bin\php\php8.1.0\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
So using e:\laravel>composer create-project laravel/laravel myproject worked and created the project folder myproject.

Comment: Using e:\laravel>composer create-project laravel/laravel myproject --ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo worked.