# How to correct the [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] error for composer laravel

Tags: php, laravel, git, github, composer-php

I have been having this error, when I try downloading dependencies for our collaboration Laravel project from github

```
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. It is recommended that you run `composer update` or `composer update <package name>`.
Package operations: 136 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Downloading balping/json-raw-encoder (v1.0.1)
 0/1 [>---------------------------]   0%  - Downloading balping/json-raw-encoder (v1.0.1)
  - Downloading balping/json-raw-encoder (v1.0.1)
  - Downloading balping/json-raw-encoder (v1.0.1)
    Failed to download balping/json-raw-encoder from dist: curl error 28 while downloading https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/balping%2Fjson-raw-encoder/repository/archive.zip?sha=e2b0ab888342b0716f1f0628e2fa13b345c5f276: Failed to connect to gitlab.com port 443 after 5205 ms: Connection timed out
    Now trying to download from source
  - Syncing balping/json-raw-encoder (v1.0.1) into cache
Cloning failed, enter your GitLab credentials to access private repos
A token will be created and stored in "/home/astraa/.config/composer/auth.json", your password will never be stored
To revoke access to this token you can visit https://gitlab.com/profile/applications
Username:
Password: 
 1/1 [============================] 100%
                                                                                                       
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                             
  curl error 28 while downloading https://gitlab.com/oauth/token: Failed to connect to gitlab.com por  
  t 443 after 5257 ms: Connection timed out                                                            
                                                                                                       

install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-suggest] [--no-dev] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-install] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

I have tried to use the solutions of this [How to correct the [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] error for composer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43996782/14915590) issue with no any success

I am running Manjaro Linux ... I would be glad if someone can help Thank You

Comment: some packages on the project are on private mode, you need to request an access to it

Comment: I'm not sure why you scattered what seem like a random collection of tags on this question, but: "connection to ... **gitlab** ... timed out". Yet: [tag:github]. Which is it, GitHub, or GitLab? You might want to figure out why you can't connect to GitLab, and whether you should be connecting to GitHub instead, before you move on to whatever the next step may be.